# Tables I create that start with "dotNetChat_" disappear after restarting MySQL

Tags: mysql, windows-8.1

**In light of new information, I have created a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22213292/cant-create-a-table-in-mysql-because-it-already-exists) that better explains the problem that I aim to fix.**

I am trying to create a collection of tables in MySQL that all start with the prefrix `dotNetChat_`. Originally I had these tables set up in another server and everything was working fine despite the fact that they are configured with the same `my.ini` file. Whenever I first create these tables, they appear normally, but after restarting MySQL, they "disappear", and try to load the table contents using MySQL Workbench produces the following error:

> Error Code: 1146. Table 'thepwf_prgminteractions.dotnetchat_testtable' doesn't exist

I checked my error log file, and here is what I found:

```
2014-03-05T23:05:31.224646Z 1 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2014-03-05T23:05:33.755361Z 2 [ERROR] InnoDB: Failed to find tablespace for table "thepwf_prgminteractions"."dotnetchat_testtable" in the cache. Attempting to load the tablespace with space id 24.
2014-03-05 18:05:33 0x1f30  InnoDB: Operating system error number 32 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means that another program is using InnoDB's files.
InnoDB: This might be a backup or antivirus software or another instance
InnoDB: of MySQL. Please close it to get rid of this error.
2014-03-05T23:05:33.760362Z 2 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for 'thepwf_prgminteractions/dotnetchat_testtable'. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html for how to resolve the issue.
2014-03-05 18:05:33 0x1f30 InnoDB: cannot calculate statistics for table "thepwf_prgminteractions"."dotnetchat_testtable" because the .ibd file is missing. For help, please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html
2014-03-05 18:05:34 0x1f30 InnoDB: cannot calculate statistics for table "thepwf_prgminteractions"."dotnetchat_testtable" because the .ibd file is missing. For help, please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html
2014-03-05 18:05:34 0x1f30 InnoDB: cannot calculate statistics for table "thepwf_prgminteractions"."dotnetchat_testtable" because the .ibd file is missing. For help, please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html
2014-03-05 18:05:35 0x1e54 InnoDB: cannot calculate statistics for table "thepwf_prgminteractions"."dotnetchat_testtable" because the .ibd file is missing. For help, please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html
```

Before thinking to check my log file, I thought that something might have been wrong with the server, so I uninstalled the server, removed all server data files, reinstalled it, put the `my.ini` configuration file that I already have made up into place, and started things back up. What could be the problem here? Whenever I try to delete any schemas that have or had tables such as this one in them, I get the following error from MySQL Workbench:

[image: Could not Drop Object]

[image]

**EDIT:** I have continued to play around with this for a while now, and after using IOBit to make sure all MySQL files were removed before reinstalling it, I am getting an error when I try to import the tables. The error from MySQL Workbench is useless, but here's something from the error log that might help.

```
2014-03-06T01:38:55.459658Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Table thepwf_prgminteractions/p2p_messagedata in the InnoDB data dictionary has tablespace id 25, but tablespace with that id or name does not exist. Have you deleted or moved .ibd files? This may also be a table created with CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE whose .ibd and .frm files MySQL automatically removed, but the table still exists in the InnoDB internal data dictionary.
InnoDB: Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html
InnoDB: for how to resolve the issue.
2014-03-06T01:38:55.464671Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Table thepwf_prgminteractions/p2p_onlineusers in the InnoDB data dictionary has tablespace id 26, but tablespace with that id or name does not exist. Have you deleted or moved .ibd files? This may also be a table created with CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE whose .ibd and .frm files MySQL automatically removed, but the table still exists in the InnoDB internal data dictionary.
InnoDB: Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html
InnoDB: for how to resolve the issue.
2014-03-06T01:38:55.468672Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Table thepwf_prgminteractions/p2pchat_betaaccesskeys in the InnoDB data dictionary has tablespace id 24, but tablespace with that id or name does not exist. Have you deleted or moved .ibd files? This may also be a table created with CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE whose .ibd and .frm files MySQL automatically removed, but the table still exists in the InnoDB internal data dictionary.
```

Comment: What is the operating system?

Comment: @D.Kasipovic Windows 8.1 Pro x64

Comment: Maybe they are one of MySQL's special table types e.g. a RAM table? That "The error means that another program is using InnoDB's files" doesn't sound too good though. I don't know generally how well MySQL runs on Windows, but if this is a development machine, I'd run it in a Linux VM.

Comment: @halfer I don't know about that. I highly doubt it because as I mentioned in my question, I have used tables with that prefix on other servers configured exactly the same as my test server.

Comment: After you create these tables, see what table type they are, and add that into the question. This depends on whether you specify your table type in your `CREATE TABLE` statements, and what your default table type is.

Comment: Do you have anti-virus or backup software that might be doing this? Also, check your disk for errors.

Comment: @halfer Is it possible that this is the problem? Besides Windows Defender that comes with 8.1, I have MalwareBytes.

Comment: @halfer I do not specify a table type. The "Engine" list in MySQL Workbench is "InnoDB." I do not know if that is what you are looking for or not.

Comment: Yes, InnoDB is your table type. They definitely should remain on disk `:-)`.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that for some reason, MySQL is denied access to InnoDB files, which it then cannot load, and continues without them. Can you verify that your process is not run twice, and that MySQL user is run under account that has access to MySQL lib directory.

I base my findings on this error:

```
[ERROR] InnoDB: Failed to find tablespace for table "thepwf_prgminteractions"."dotnetchat_testtable" in the cache. Attempting to load the tablespace with space id 24.
2014-03-05 18:05:33 0x1f30  InnoDB: Operating system error number 32 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means that another program is using InnoDB's files.
InnoDB: This might be a backup or antivirus software or another instance
InnoDB: of MySQL. Please close it to get rid of this error.
```

And error 32, based on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx means:

```
ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION
32 (0x20)
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

Which means, as I said, that files are being locked by another process. And it is happening when you restart MySQL because when you create them, MySQL has them open, and another process cannot lock them. As soon as MySQL service is stopped (for restart), another process locks the files, and MySQL cannot open them when it starts up again.

To see locked files on your system, and which process is holding it locked you can use http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx

You would need to run CMD Prompt as administrator, and type something like:

```
handle.exe thepwf_
```

Which should show which process is holding the files locked.

Let me know what you find.

Comment: I use a program called Duplicati (http://www.duplicati.com/) to back up certain files on my computer to a remote server, and I currently have Duplicati set up to back up `ProgramData` folder for MySQL. Could this be the source of the problem?

Comment: I have taken a screenshot of the unfortunate results of the command console and posted it in my question.

Comment: Yes, I see. Try to run it like `handle.exe > c:\handles.txt` because without parameters it shows all handles. Then when you open `c:\handles.txt` in notepad, try to find something related to MySQL or ProgramData or something like that, it might be holding the whole folder locked.

Comment: I don't entirely understand what it is you are telling me to do here. I ran the test on dotNetChat_, and the only thing coming up is `mysqld.exe`.

Comment: When you run `handle.exe > c:\handles.txt` it will create handles.txt on your C disk, with all open handles. Then, you open that file in notepad and try to find anything related to mysql or programdata.

Comment: Okay. I did it and as far as I can tell `mysqld.exe` is the only thing  using the files.

Comment: Shut down mysql and see what process gets the files after mysql is shut down.

Comment: @DavidB: you could also shut down various tools (Duplicati, Defender, MalwareBytes etc) one by one and see which helps resolve the problem.

Comment: I will do the first one.

Comment: Did the first along with the second, and neither work.

Comment: Apparently MySQL's uninstaller doesn't do a very good job removing leftover files. I have uninstalled MySQL using IOBit uninstaller. Hopefully doing this will have removed whatever it causing the problem. None of the solutions given to me so far have worked.

Comment: Please see my latest edit for more information about the results of my attempt to completely uninstall and reinstall.