# Can't create a table in MySQL because "it already exists"

Tags: mysql, windows-8.1

I am having an issue with MySQL, relating to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22211479/tables-i-create-that-start-with-dotnetchat-disappear-after-restarting-mysql).

I recently needed to remove a table from MySQL, and now need to create a new one in its place. I am having a hard time with this because, as MySQL Workbench says, "The table already exists." Since the error from MySQL Workbench is not particularly helpful, here's some stuff that I pulled out of my error log. What's the problem?

I am running MySQL 5.7 on Windows 8.1 Pro x64.

```
2014-03-06T01:38:55.459658Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Table thepwf_prgminteractions/p2p_messagedata in the InnoDB data dictionary has tablespace id 25, but tablespace with that id or name does not exist. Have you deleted or moved .ibd files? This may also be a table created with CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE whose .ibd and .frm files MySQL automatically removed, but the table still exists in the InnoDB internal data dictionary.
InnoDB: Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html
InnoDB: for how to resolve the issue.
2014-03-06T01:38:55.464671Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Table thepwf_prgminteractions/p2p_onlineusers in the InnoDB data dictionary has tablespace id 26, but tablespace with that id or name does not exist. Have you deleted or moved .ibd files? This may also be a table created with CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE whose .ibd and .frm files MySQL automatically removed, but the table still exists in the InnoDB internal data dictionary.
InnoDB: Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html
InnoDB: for how to resolve the issue.
2014-03-06T01:38:55.468672Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Table thepwf_prgminteractions/p2pchat_betaaccesskeys in the InnoDB data dictionary has tablespace id 24, but tablespace with that id or name does not exist. Have you deleted or moved .ibd files? This may also be a table created with CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE whose .ibd and .frm files MySQL automatically removed, but the table still exists in the InnoDB internal data dictionary.
```

Answer (score 1):

As the table exists then just remove it with drop table (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/drop-table.html)

i.e.

```
drop table <table name>
```

You must have done something wrong as the table still exists.

Can check this with `select`

i.e.

```
select * from <table name>
```

Comment: `drop table thepwf_prgminteractions` returns an "Unknown Table" error.

Comment: @davidB - are you using the right database i.e. `use <database>` before hand

Comment: Yes. Also, the query that I put in my comment is wrong. I meant to say `p2pChat_betaAccessKeys`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks your innodb tablespace has been corrupted.

Checkout this post from percona

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/07/04/recovering-innodb-table-corruption/

And these tools

http://www.percona.com/software/percona-toolkit

They will save you!

Well I don't know how well they run on windows but what the tools do should be about the same.

Comment: I have no idea how to use these tools to solve the problem even after reading through both pages. I have noticed that the problem only occurs with tables that have an underscore in their name when I have `lower_case_table_names` set to `2`.

Answer (score 0):

Go to where your mysql folder is installed:
C:\Apps\mysql-5.6.25-win64\data\databasename

Under databasename you will find your tablename. Delete this table manually and create it again using SQL Create Table command.